# N Game character Physics

Tags: math, ios4, physics

For my 2d platform game am following 2 articles from creator of N N+ game. Two article covers how the collision is handled and a broad phase collision detection by storing all the AABB shapes info in to tile map along with some other potential information required for collision.No where on the Internet how the player character movement handling is explained.

http://www.madgravityradio.com/ngame.html

I tried with small rectangular piece in the place of player , the result I got is rectangle is very responsive as far as the collision concern but not realistic though (I have no idea how to tilt the player rectangle to some angle when stepping down or up on Slope edges.).

What type of object the player is comprised of? Is the player kept inside a box shape and the box is translated? Please shed some light on how the character is controlled , concept behid this virtual player? I read somewhere Rag doll is used.

I have few more general questions
In SAT how to handle/apply the minimum translation vector to make the movement more realistic?
I haven't started creating tile map for this iphone game , I do have some experience in title map creation for flash games. No idea how to handle iphone memory efficiently  - any recommendations please?

Comment: This is unclear. What is the "unrealistic" property that you want to change? If the rectangle doesn't look enough like a person, then let it move as a rectangle but render it as a person. If the *movement* is unrealistic, then tell us what the unrealistic part is.

Comment: @Beta : Yes the "movement is unrealistic" with gravity , any comments how to handle both SAT and gravity?

Comment: I don't know what SAT is, but I understand gravity pretty well. Do you know how to apply an acceleration to the rectangle?

Comment: Oh sorry - SAT is separate axis theorem for handling collision(http://physics2d.com/content/separation-axis). regarding the acceleration I have very basic idea , no idea about the computation/real physics formulas. Time being am followed this tutorial http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/vectors/tut04.html .

Comment: Trying to tackle both problems at once is unwise. How far have you gotten in that tutorial?

Comment: I agree but the problem am having is , player object (x,y) coordinates gets affected by two different factors one is gravity(y) and at the other on is the resultant vector(after collision collision). For example when the virtual player is on the slope(Colliding) -  SAT returns a vector which tells how much amount of deviation on (x,y) , on the other hand gravity is also kept applied on y (y value increments) - am struggling how to handle this two affecting factors together and applying the same to the player?

Comment: Ah! Just add them. If SAT returns a vector (x1, y1) and gravity adds a vector (0, y2), then the vector you should use is (x1, y1+y2). It is also important to understand *position*, *velocity* and *acceleration* vectors, and be careful not to mix them up.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is [collision response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response) - ie now that you have detected a collision and have the collision data, what do you do with it to produce a meaningful response.  This is a pretty big topic so maybe investigate it and come back with some more specific questions.  [Here's a basic primer](http://chrishecker.com/images/e/e7/Gdmphys3.pdf) and google/wikipedia will take you much farther.